# npm - install angular/cli from local package(offline)

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I want to install `angular/cli` from a local package, I have downloaded the package folder with `package.json` and all the rest of the files:

```
bin
commands
CONTRIBUTING.md
ember-cli
lib
LICENSE
models
node_modules
package.json
plugins
README.md
tasks
upgrade
utilities
```

I have tried `npm install 'path/to/package'` and the error log :

```
6041 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "C:\\Users\\t207322\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\@angular\\cli\\1.4.4\\package"
6042 verbose node v9.3.0
6043 verbose npm  v5.5.1
6044 error path C:\Users\t207322\node_modules\cryptiles\node_modules
6045 error code EPERM
6046 error errno -4048
6047 error syscall scandir
6048 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\t207322\node_modules\cryptiles\node_modules'
6048 error  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\t207322\node_modules\cryptiles\node_modules'
6048 error   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir \'C:\\Users\\t207322\\node_modules\\cryptiles\\node_modules\'',
6048 error   errno: -4048,
6048 error   code: 'EPERM',
6048 error   syscall: 'scandir',
6048 error   path: 'C:\\Users\\t207322\\node_modules\\cryptiles\\node_modules' }
6049 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
6050 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
```

I had also tried inserting the package to 'AppData\Roaming\npm-cache' and running `npm link` with same result :

```
2017 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "link"
2018 verbose node v9.3.0
2019 verbose npm  v5.5.1
2020 error path C:\Users\t207322\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\@angular\cli\1.4.4\package\node_modules\scss-tokenizer\node_modules
2021 error code EPERM
2022 error errno -4048
2023 error syscall scandir
2024 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\t207322\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\@angular\cli\1.4.4\package\node_modules\scss-tokenizer\node_modules'
2024 error  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\t207322\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\@angular\cli\1.4.4\package\node_modules\scss-tokenizer\node_modules'
2024 error   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir \'C:\\Users\\t207322\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\@angular\\cli\\1.4.4\\package\\node_modules\\scss-tokenizer\\node_modules\'',
2024 error   errno: -4048,
2024 error   code: 'EPERM',
2024 error   syscall: 'scandir',
2024 error   path: 'C:\\Users\\t207322\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\@angular\\cli\\1.4.4\\package\\node_modules\\scss-tokenizer\\node_modules' }
2025 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
2026 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
```

So, is there another way to install a angular/cli using a local package?

Comment: does the package.json define all the packages you want to install?

Comment: I just want to install angular/cli, what do you mean by all the packages?

Comment: what happens when you run npm install

Comment: i have posted full error log for `npm install`.

Comment: yes, but just npm install takes care of all the package dependencies in package.json (vs. calling it with a path). but, i don't think that is your probelm. You are getting an EPERM error which means your files are in read-only mode. Try going to the folder in windows and checking the permissions. Make sure it has write access. Sometimes when you download a project from the INternet windows will set the folder access to read-only. If you are in Llinux, you can try chmod 777 on that folder and run again. Check this.

Comment: If that doesn't work, some other things to try: 1) clean your cache: npm cache clean --force 2) roll back your version of npm as it might be an issue with the current version. E.g: npm install npm@5.3 -g